# How to extract an element from an XML file?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following simple XML fragment shown below. What would the T-SQL look like if I wanted to just extract the 'EntityFriendlyName' attribute?

```
<SimpleRuleValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <EntityId>0</EntityId>
    <EntityFriendlyName>ALine</EntityFriendlyName>
</SimpleRuleValue>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
SELECT CAST(X.SomeXML AS XML).value('(SimpleRuleValue/EntityFriendlyName)[1]','nvarchar(1000)') AS EntityFriendlyName
FROM XmlSource X
```

Edit:
[A little more information.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx)

Comment: Assuming that the column `X` already is of type XML, you could simplify to `SELECT X.value(.....)`

Comment: Correct marc_s, this was actually a generic solution to a similar problem I once faced (the data type in that case was varchar i believe).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
declare @x xml

set @x = '<SimpleRuleValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
              <EntityId>0</EntityId>
              <EntityFriendlyName>ALine</EntityFriendlyName>
          </SimpleRuleValue>'

select @x.query('data(SimpleRuleValue/EntityFriendlyName)')
```